# Check if already asked about location services authorization

Tags: swift, core-location, ios11

1. I ask a user for *WhenInUse* authorization for Location Services with `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization`.
2. Then, later in my app I ask for an upgrade to *Always* authorization with `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization`. In iOS 11 users can, however, choose to stay with *WhenInUse* - let's assume that.
3. Let's say the user open the app again and I want to show a dialog saying "Change Location Services settings if you want the app to work in background" in that case.
4. Then, I check what authorization status is with `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` and I get `.authorizationWhenInUse`. Now I don't know if I have already asked for Always permissions before or not.
5. `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization` won't have any effect
   if I already asked the user about it, how do I know that is the
   case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had that case that I wanted to know if requesting Always authorization has any effect, but I couldn't find any solution to that (that wouldn't include UX redesign of my app), so eventually I went with User Defaults like:

```
// Define a defaults key
fileprivate struct DefaultsKeys {
    static let hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization = 
        "hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization"
}

// Then in later your code
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults:[DefaultsKeys.hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization: false])
let hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: DefaultsKeys.hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization)
if hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization {
    // E.g. show a dialog saying user needs to change it manually in settings etc.
} else {
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: DefaultsKeys.hasAlreadyRequestedAlwaysAuthorization)
}
```